# All PHP Pages are showing up completely blank

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I programmed a website, no need to get into more detail about it but it works and does not require any DB or something like that. But on my new Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS Server all PHP pages show up blank. I have installed Apache2, PHP5 and something I don't know what it is for with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I have tried to deinstall and reinstall all of these components without and luck. None of the PHP pages show up in my browser, they show up blank and with a blank source, whereas all my pure .html pages work fine.

Is there any way to get it working, I would be happy to post more information but I do not know where I should get that.

**Error Log:**

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jul 23 00:36:05 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 23 00:36:16 2012] [error] [client 217.227.25.35] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in /var/www/vtest5532/Header.php on line 19
[Mon Jul 23 00:36:17 2012] [error] [client 217.227.25.35] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in /var/www/vtest5532/Header.php on line 19
[Mon Jul 23 00:38:09 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jul 23 00:38:10 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 23 00:38:59 2012] [error] [client 180.76.5.62] File does not exist: /var/www/Forum
[Mon Jul 23 01:10:36 2012] [error] [client 66.249.68.165] File does not exist: /var/www/Forum
[Mon Jul 23 01:10:36 2012] [error] [client 66.249.68.165] File does not exist: /var/www/Forum
```

Comment: Did you check the apache config to check if the php module is enabled?

Comment: If you view the source of the "blank" page do you see anything? I'm guessing you will see your PHP source code...

Comment: The pages that are blank im figuring this is your project? have you tried with just `<?php phpinfo();?>` ? if it works you can then compare with your dev server to see if your missing something. perhaps your project uses curl which is not installed and you have no error reporting within your code and its just dying, check your server logs `error.log`, also 500 errors related to not having mod_rewrite enabled, and perhaps your using mod_rewrite.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `500 errors related to not having mod_rewrite enabled, and perhaps your using mod_rewrite` - Apache would send its own error document in this case. If this is an error and not simply a missing `AddHandler` (which my money is on) then the error is with PHP or you would see a stock Apache error doc.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is configured not to display errors by default. If you check the Apache error log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` you should see the cause of the problem. If this is a development machine you should also change your `php.ini` file to a more dev-friendly setup (show errors, `error_reporting` at max). If it's a production server then leave the php.ini as-is.

Comment: Hmmm... The only thing about this is that if you get a "blank" page, it's probably a parse error, or a fatal error that occurred before any output was produced by the script. In which case you would get a 500 error, and the browser would show it's own error page, because the server did not send an error document.

Comment: the error log doesn't seem to help (at least me) here is what it said: "sorry can't post to long" but i doubt that that has anything to do with it the error includes things like: maysql db, connect fail. it doesn't even specify a client.

Comment: @user1544585 Please edit the question with the information from the error log.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /var/www/vtest5532/Header.php on line 19` is your main problem, although there are some other things there that may need fixing

Comment: @user1544585 You have quite few problems there, any one or several of which could be causing your problem. First thing to do would be to correct those errors you're getting when Apache starts - there are some very commonly used modules which are failing to load and this will cause you problems, even if it's not at the moment. If you just hit refresh on a PHP file in your browser, do any more error messages appear? What is the HTTP status code you get from a request to a PHP script?

Comment: that is a very old site, it is no longer used. Thats why i said its not because of the page. not even <?php phpinfo(); ?> is showing up. @daverandon ok but where would i start fixing them?

Comment: Ok, my problem is sort of solved, I am upgrading the server tomorrow anyway so i will come back here if i see any errors with the new machine. Thank you very much though.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me (Ubuntu 22.04, PHP8.1-fpm):

1. purge php8.1-fpm packets,
2. running these commands in terminal:

> ```
> apt install php8.1-fpm
> a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
> a2enconf php8.1-fpm
> ```